# input type color always open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need your help, I'm using input type color and I need the color picker to always show up without clicking can we do this using html or css or js/jquery or anyway.

Thank you in advance.

google, youtube, didn't find anything also in stackoverflow

Comment: You can't do that with the base input color, but you can use js ones

Comment: Thank you LK77,
do you have any article on that?

Comment: No i don't have any for jquery, but i'm sure there is plenty on internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, without JS there‘s no way to do that. You can use a js-library like [iro.js](https://iro.js.org/).

It’s a free, easy-to-use and powerful library.